# Method of false Position in Optimization: Taking Derivatives

Tags: derivatives, optimization, algorithms

The method of false position at optimization updates $x_{k+1} = x_*$ where $x_*$ is a stationary point of the following function, based on the knowledge of $x_k, \ x_{k-1}$ and $f(x_k), \frac{d f(x_k)}{dx}, \frac{df(x_{k-1})}{dx}$:
$$q(x) = f(x_k) + \frac{df(x_k)}{dx}(x - x_k) + \frac{\frac{df(x_{k-1})}{dx} - \frac{d f(x_k)}{dx}}{x_{k-1}-x_k} \frac{(x-x_k)^2}{2} .$$
It is given in a book that the derivative of $q(x)$ is:
$$\frac{dq(x)}{dx} = \frac{df(x_{k})}{dx} + \frac{\frac{df(x_{k-1})}{dx} - \frac{d f(x_k)}{dx}}{x_{k-1} - x_k} (x - x_k).$$
So it seems like it is assumed that $\frac{df(x_k)}{dx}$ is **not** a function of $x$, but a constant.

I really don't follow this assumption. Does it make sense to fix the value of $\frac{df(x_k)}{dx}$ and keep $x$ as a variable, and take the derivative?

Comment: $x_k$ is just the previous iterate, and so $f(x_k)$ is just a fixed constant. Maybe try actually evaluating $q(x)$ for various values of $x$ and see what happens. That term $f(x_k)$ will always be the same no matter what choice you make for the value of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's very common in optimization to approximate arbitrary functions by quadratic ones as $q$. $q$ is somewhat a Taylor expansion of  $f$ even though it's not totally true since the second derivative is approached by finite difference.